# How do i get to pick only a particular data type

Tags: html, json

in json file,

```
Const = 
[{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "The Boys",
    "date": "2022",
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "type": "series"
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "name": "Money Heist",
    "date": "2020",
    "genre": "Action",
    "type": "series"
}, {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "John Wick",
    "date": "2022",
    "genre": "Action",
    "type": "movie"
}
```

I want to only display only one particular type. For instance, I don't want to display all files but only "type": "series" on my page without showing the others

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

here's the old school way to do this.  >Look into the js filter() function

```js
Const = 
[{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "The Boys",
    "date": "2022",
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "type": "series"
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "name": "Money Heist",
    "date": "2020",
    "genre": "Action",
    "type": "series"
}, {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "John Wick",
    "date": "2022",
    "genre": "Action",
    "type": "movie"
}]

cnt = Const.length;
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
  if (Const[i]['type'] == "series"){
     console.log(Const[i]['id'])
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "The Boys",
    "date": "2022",
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "type": "series"
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "name": "Money Heist",
    "date": "2020",
    "genre": "Action",
    "type": "series"
}, {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "John Wick",
    "date": "2022",
    "genre": "Action",
    "type": "movie"
}];

const filteredData = data.filter(item => item.type === "series");
console.log(filteredData);
```